# Capistrano set configuration environment variables

Tags: bash, capistrano, web-deployment

I'm shocked I haven't been able to find this with googling but I was wondering how to setup a capistrano deploy where the environment variables store the important config variables (api keys, etc). I know how to access them in the code, I just can't get the environment variables setup.

I'm running Ubuntu 12.10 X64 Server and capistrano doesn't seem to be loading my .bashrc file.

Where can I put the environment variables so that they're loaded when any commands are run.

Comment: How are you running capistrano out of curiousity?

Answer (score 0):

You can set environment variables by creating the `~/.ssh/environment` file as follows:

```
PATH=/opt/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
LANG=C
```

Note that you should set `PermitUserEnvironment` to `yes` in the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and restart the `sshd` daemon.

Comment: Is this on the server or client?